# Vue.js: update child json data format in db

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

I need to update only rating value in `commented_type` column. On Laravel I using for that like commented_type>rating. But I do not know how to do vue.js.

JSON column like this:

```
commented_type
 {"type": "review", "rating": 5}



updateReview: function () {
    var reviewData = {
        id:584,
        commented_type>rating:'4',//It does not work like that
    };
    this.$http.patch('/review/584',reviewData).then((response) => {

        console.log(response.data);

    }, (response) => {
        // error callback
        console.log('error response review update')
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your JSON currently in string form? Try using JavaScript's `JSON.parse()` if you need to get an object.

Otherwise, it sounds like you're just asking about [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) in JS. Try this:

```
commented_type['rating']
```